# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/codegen/CodegenFallback$class

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I am applying a spatial function in spark3 environment with the below code and getting the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/codegen/CodegenFallback$class

environment: spark3, scala2.12

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.language.postfixOps
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.{Coordinate, Geometry, GeometryFactory}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode     
import org.datasyslab.geosparksql.utils.{Adapter, GeoSparkSQLRegistrator}
GeoSparkSQLRegistrator.registerAll(spark.sqlContext)

spark.sql("select *, ST_GeomFromText(geom) as geomnew from geotable").show()
```